# Filezilla c# 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized

Tags: c#, server, filezilla

I have created a ftp server using Filezilla. I am trying to upload a single file using c# code. My cide is very simple a functino called upload:

```
static void UploadFile(string filepath)
    {
     string m_FtpHost = "http://ip:port/";
     string m_FtpUsername = "userID";
     string m_FtpPassword = "pass";
     // Get an instance of WebClient
     WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
     // parse the ftp host and file into a uri path for the upload
     Uri uri = new Uri(m_FtpHost + new FileInfo(filepath).Name);
     // set the username and password for the FTP server
     client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(m_FtpUsername, m_FtpPassword);
     // upload the file asynchronously, non-blocking.

     client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "STOR", filepath);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      UploadFile("file.pdf"); 
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

In the Filezilla server gui I am getting the following messages:

```
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> STOR  /file.pdf HTTP/1.1
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> 530 Please log in with USER and PASS first.
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> Host: ip:port
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> Content-Length: 481868
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> Expect: 100-continue
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> Connection: Keep-Alive
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000017)11/23/2015 10:47:19 AM - (not logged in) (ip)> disconnected.
```

Any idea what might be wrong here? 
EDIT: I tried to change http with ftp in the UploadFile. Now I am receiving the following:

```
(000019)11/23/2015 10:59:53 AM - chrathan user (ip)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000019)11/23/2015 10:59:53 AM - user (ip)> TYPE I
(000019)11/23/2015 10:59:53 AM - user (ip)> 200 Type set to I
(000019)11/23/2015 10:59:53 AM - user (ip)> PASV
(000019)11/23/2015 10:59:53 AM - user (ip)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (ip with comma)
(000019)11/23/2015 10:59:53 AM - user (ip)> STOR file.pdf
(000019)11/23/2015 10:59:53 AM - user (ip)> 150 Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/file.pdf"
(000019)11/23/2015 10:59:53 AM - user (ip)> 550 can't access file.
(000019)11/23/2015 10:59:53 AM - user (ip)> disconnected.
```

EDIT2: Basically the folder I try to have access is a network share disk. When I changed to a local folder in my pc everything works. My issue finally is how can I have access to a network share disk?

Comment: How about using a WebRequest with WebRequestMethods.FTP.Put? It seems that the login process is not working. The server requests your authorization credentials and the answer is a Content-Type, so, use the right request for your upload

Comment: I change http to ftp and I get new error message now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `m_FtpHost` variable is set to use http, it needs to be `ftp://ip:port/`.

Thats why the first line of your log is showing: STOR /file.pdf **HTTP**/1.1

Comment: Does the folder you are trying to upload to have write permissions for the account that the FileZilla server is running under?

Comment: Basically is a Network share drive thus it seems that it is not that straight forward.

Comment: Ahh, I see. This sticky post on the FileZilla forums regarding setting up FileZilla Server to use network shared might help you: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=9200

Comment: Thus, in fact that link propose to create a new user in my windows and use it just to run the filezilla server service. Am I right?

Comment: That all depends on your particular environment / domain etc. You don't necessarily need a NEW account for this, you could use an existing account, but from an administrative point of view, it would be recommended to have a dedicated account for the purpose. The important aspect being that both the local server account that FileZilla is running as and the remote network share that you are connecting to need to have the correct permissions granted.